# how to load JSON file using popup into variable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

So, I have created a popup here to load an external JSON file from the system.
I want to store that JSON file into one variable in the javascript file. how to achieve this using jquery or javascript?

```css
/* Style this however you like */
#input-file-replacer {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="file" name="input-name" style="display: none;" />
  <span id="input-file-replacer">Select file</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Note that, despite the title of the duplicate, nothing is uploaded. It reads the data from the `files` collection of the input using a `FileReader`, exactly as you need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `onchange` function. Then access the `files` object inside the function

```js
function uploadFile() {
  let x = document.getElementById("file");
  console.log(x.files)
}
```

```css
#input-file-replacer {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input id ='file' type="file" name="input-name" style="display: none;" onchange="uploadFile()" />
  <span id="input-file-replacer">Select file</span>
</label>
```

Comment: perfect! accepting your answer :)

Comment: @ShreeBatale happy to help. Do necessary validation like checking if files exist in x

Comment: I have one JSON file I want to store that JSON file content in x variable possible?

Comment: You may need `new FormData()`

Comment: could you please add that in your code?

Comment: actually I don't know how to do it!

Comment: @ShreeBatale you can check this 
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/